# Use ResourceDictionary with other Styles in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I am trying to use a ResourceDictionary and a Style in my WPF program. When I only have ResourceDictionary in `<Window.Resources>` everything works fine but as soon as I add a `<Style>` the program displays "Resource not found" for the Dictionary and I get an error "The resource "PlusMinusExpander" could not be resolved."

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CurrencyCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#dddddd" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="hello" Source="Assets/PlusMinusExpanderStyles.xaml" />
</Window.Resources>


<Expander Header="Plus Minus Expander" Style="{StaticResource PlusMinusExpander}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="292">
    <Grid Background="Transparent">
        <TextBlock>Item1</TextBlock>
     </Grid>
</Expander>
```

I want to be able to do `Style="{StaticResource PlusMinusExpander}"` even after adding the CurrencyCellStyle Style. 
I have seen similar questions online but none of their solutions have worked for me yet. Is there a way to use both the Style and the ResourceDictionary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of `Window.Resources` property is `ResourceDictionary`, so cannot put two different types of XAML element as brothers. Instead, you should:

- Put a separated `ResourceDictionary` into the `Window.Resources` property and write the `Style` inside the `ResourceDictionary`.
- Remove the `x:Key` property from the `ResourceDictionary`.

---

```
<FrameworkElement.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/PlusMinusExpanderStyles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <Style x:Key="CurrencyCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#dddddd" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</FrameworkElement.Resources>
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining. This worked perfectly for me.

Comment: I'm glad it can help you.